# Reading and Looping Through A JSON File in BASH

Tags: json, bash, jq

I've got a JSON file (see below) called department_groups.json.

Essentially if I gave an argument of `commercial` I'd like it to return:

```
commercial-team@domain.com

commercial-updates@domain.com
```

Can anyone guide/help me with doing this?

```
{
    "legal": {
        "google_groups":[
            ["Legal", "legal@domain.com"],
            ["Legal Team", "legal-team@domain.com"],
            ["Compliance Checks", "compliance@domain.com"]
        ],
        "samba_groups": ""
     },
    "commercial":{
        "google_groups":[
            ["Commercial Team", "commercial-team@domain.com"],
            ["Commercial Updates", "commercial-updates@domain.com"]
        ],
        "samba_groups": ""  
    },
    "technology":{
        "google_groups":[
            ["Technology", "technology@domain.com"],
            ["Incidents", "incidents@domain.com"]
        ],
        "samba_groups": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the second element in each array in `google_groups` under the key `commercial`, or do you just want all the second elements which match the string `commercial` in some way?

Comment: I suggest you do it in other languages, such as Python instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns the second element in each array in the `google_groups` property of the `commercial` property:

```
jq --arg key commercial '.[$key].google_groups | .[] | .[1]' file
```

Use `jq -r` to output in "raw" format (lose the double quotes).

```
$ key=commercial
$ jq -r --arg key "$key" '.[$key].google_groups | .[] | .[1]' file
commercial-team@domain.com
commercial-updates@domain.com
```

I used `--arg` in these examples to show how it is used, optionally with a shell variable. If, on the other hand, `commercial` was just a fixed string, then you could simplify:

```
jq -r '.commercial.google_groups | .[] | .[1]' file
```

To process each line of the output, you can just use a shell `while read` loop:

```
key=commercial
while read -r email; do
  echo "$email"
  # process each email individually here
done < <(jq -r --arg key "$key" '.[$key].google_groups | .[] | .[1]' file)
```

Here I am using a process substitution `<()`, which acts like a file that can be processed by the shell. One advantage of doing this, over using a pipe, is that no subshell is created. Among other things, this means that the variables used within the loop remain in scope after the `while` block, so you can use them later.

If you prefer to use a pipe, just remove the part after `done` and move the command up to the first line:

```
jq ... | while read -r email; do # etc.
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks so much Tom!

If I want to loop through these outputs, how would I go about doing that?
E.g., 
    for each email_address in email
    //my code to the email_address...
    done

What I'm trying to is add each of these mailing lists to a user. I'm using a JSON file because I want it to be editable and easy to read for other people in the future.

Comment: @Jonathan no problem. I edited to show how you could process the results in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

As @TomFenech noted, the requirements are somewhat unclear, but if it's the email addresses you want, the following variant of his answer may be of interest:

```
key=commercial
$ jq -r --arg key "$key" '.[$key].google_groups[][] | select(test("@"))' department_groups.json
commercial-team@domain.com
commercial-updates@domain.com
```